# Некорректная работа функции

Tags: строки, c++

Некорректная работа блока кода:

```
do {
    b = F[i];
    if (b.find(G)) {
        N++;
        b.clear();
        i++;
    } else {
        b.clear();
        i++;
    }
} while (i < F.length());
```

N++ делается для каждого символа из string F; хотя в string G; таких символов не существует. В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Дайте больше кода.

Answer (score 3):

[std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

**If the content is not found, the member value npos is returned.**

Т.е. сравнение должно выглядеть так:

`if (b.find(G) != std::string::npos)`